# Global variable returned as undefined when it is again declared locally in a block and referred before the declaration in the block.

Tags: javascript, global-variables, local-variables

```
var a = 10;
function example(){
    alert(a);
    var a = 5;    
}
example();
```

This code alerts undefined.

My question is why variable a is alerting "undefined" instead of returning global variable's value.

My thanks to everyone in advance. I hope someone will clarify it for me.

Comment: Look into "hoisting"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside Javascript functions each *declaration* of variable is always hoisted to the top of it, but not *assignment* of its value. What you're really executing is:

```
var a = 10;
function example(){
  var a;      //undefined!
  alert(a);   //still undefined!
  a = 5;      //only now it becomes 5    
}
example();
```

Read more about `hoisting` in Javascript: [Javascript hoisting explained](http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/04/20/javascript-hoisting-explained/)

To avoid declaring new, local variable, and instead just use already defined global one:

```
var a = 10;
function example(){
  alert(a);
  a = 5;    
}
example();
```

This looks like what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You explained it very well to me. I just saw this code snippet in a website. I was perplexed with the behaviour. I was unaware of Javascript hoisting. That was the keyword actually.

Answer (score 0):

Because of *hoisting* of variable `a`. The below is what is happening. The `a` inside the function is getting hoisted to the top of the function body, and it shadows the `a` which is outside the function and has the value of `10`.

And you're alerting `a` before it was initialized, in the case of which, `a` will have the default value of `undefined`.

```
var a = 10;
function example(){
    var a; // this is undefined and shadows the global a
    alert(a);
    a = 5;
    alert(a); // 5    
}
example();
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, If you declare a global variable and a local variable with the same name, *the local variable will have priority when you attempt to use the variable inside a function*. That being said, since you try to alert the value of `a` and you have defined a local variable with the same name in your function scope, in the alert the value of the local variable would be appear. However, you declare the variable after the alert statement. Hence it's value is undefined.

If you try to run the following snippet, in which we have removed the declaration of another variable with name `a`, you will get the expected behavior.

```js
var a = 10;

function example(){
    alert(a);
    a = 5;    
}

example();
```